# Do separate pieces of EMT conduit qualify as "pull points"?

Tags: electrical, conduit

**Question:** Do two separate pieces of EMT conduit joined by a connector qualify as a "pull point"?

**Background:** 
I need to make six 90 degree turns in 2" EMT conduit to route wire for a new sub-panel which means my run is subject to NEC 2011 clause 358.26:

```
358.26 Bends — Number in One Run. There shall not be
more than the equivalent of four quarter bends (360 degrees
total) between pull points, for example, conduit bodies and
boxes.
```

[image]
However, I cannot find anywhere that the NEC specifically defines a "pull point" other than the examples of "conduit bodies and boxes". It makes sense to me that "conduit bodies" means having two separate pieces of conduit joined with a connector (as per the connectors to the 90 degree bend in the above picture) because the conduit bodies can be separated to allow for pulling without over-stressing the wire, but I want to confirm if this is the correct interpretation.

Or, do I need a special elbow pull fitting like shown below (the picture shows smaller conduit), or are these fittings just for convenience if you later decide to pull more wire through the conduit?

[image: Picture credit of www.diyadvice.com]

*Picture credit of http://www.diyadvice.com/diy/electrical/cable/metal-conduit/*

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to all for your answers. I somehow overlooked the definition of conduit body in the standard:

```
Conduit Body. A separate portion of a conduit or tubing
system that provides access through a removable cover(s)
to the interior of the system at a junction of two or more
sections of the system or at a terminal point of the system.
Boxes such as FS and FD or larger cast or sheet metal
boxes are not classified as conduit bodies.
```

Comment: An elbow (sweep) is not a conduit body, nor a box, so it is not a pull point. If you swap out the sweep for a conduit body, then it's a pull point. Though if the conduit is already strapped in place, you'll likely need a couple nipples to fit the conduit body in place. Also mind the orientation of the conduit body, with respect to the pull direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NO! Regular couplings, those in the first image, are NOT pull points. Pull points are conduit bodies or boxes, or even those silly little elbows in the second image.

My suggestion would be to install a conduit body at strategic locations. For your installation you really only need one.

Conduit bodies:

[image: Conduit bodies]

[image]

Comment: Chortle - someone (I assume not you, presume the image is from elsewhere) missed the LB in your collection of conduit bodies - I see two C and two LR, One LL and one T, but no LB.

Comment: Another kind of conduit body is a junction box.  You only need one kind of box and you can splice in it and branch off it.  I like access points every 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Conduit is typically mounted and strapped so you cannot readily separate the joints shown in the first picture.  Pull points would mean a way to pull the wire without separating the joints of the conduit themselves.

Do it right the first time and make it easy on you or anyone else who has to work on it later.

Comment: "pull the with without"?

Comment: I assume he meant "pull the wire without". I made an edit to fix the typo.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about linear conduit which is assembled and tightened.  The Code you cite specifically talks about a removable cover.  You must complete construction of the conduit system, including strapping it down to resist pulling forces, before you are allowed to load any wires into it. Obviously, once wires are in it, you are not to take it apart without first pulling the wires out.

We see it all the time where people pull the wires as they go, and find themselves solving simple problems by misusing conduit bodies to make sharp turns.  They either position the body so the cover is inaccessible (lid up against the wall, later covered up with drywall etc.)  Obviously that kind of plan does not work if you are obliged to pull the wires last.

In fact, you should **buy the wires last**.  So many times we see novices learn more about their situation, and realize they are better off with a different wire than they selected.  But it's too late! They already bought it.  So don't - buy the wire for the complicated work after everything else is done.